# Creating a ListView in Fragment that Retrieves Data from a Server

Tags: android, listview, android-asynctask, fragment, android-listfragment

I've been attempting to create a ListView in a fragment that gets data from a server, but so far have been unsuccessful. I've been using the following site: [Vogella](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html#listfragments) for learning on how to implement ListView in a fragment, but I am having difficulties when trying to populate data from a server.

```
package com.example.ips_alpha;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import android.util.Log;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TableLayout;

public class Gold_Visitors2 extends ListFragment{

//JSON Node names (level, sensorID, value)
String SPACES = "spaces"; //String array name of php
String LEVEL = "level";
String SENSORID = "sensorID";
String VALUE = "value";
//pspace JSONArray
JSONArray pspace = null;
String[] levels = new String[]{LEVEL, SENSORID, VALUE};

int [] ids = new int[]{};

private static String url = "http://www.example.com/getUsers12.php";


public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_gold_visitors, null);


    new MyAsyncTask().execute();
    return view;

}

class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> > {


    //Hashmap for ListView
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> levelList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>doInBackground(String... params) {

//Creating JSON Parser instance
        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

        //getting JSON string from URL

        JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);

        try {
            //Getting Array of spaces
            pspace = json.getJSONArray(SPACES);

            //looping through all spaces
            for(int i = 0; i < pspace.length(); i++){
                JSONObject p = pspace.getJSONObject(i);

            //Storing each json item in variable
                String level = p.getString(LEVEL);
                String sensorID = p.getString(SENSORID);
                String value = p.getString(VALUE);
            //creating new HashMap

                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap <String, String>();
            //adding each child node to HashMap Key =>
                map.put(LEVEL, level);
                map.put(SENSORID, sensorID);
                map.put(VALUE, value);

            //adding HashList to ArrayList
            }
        }catch(JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        return levelList;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> levelList) {

        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), levelList, R.layout.fragment_gold_visitors, levels, ids);
        setListAdapter(adapter);


    }


}
}
```

The following is the layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
    android:id="@id/android:list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView>
```

Currently my app is compiling and does not crash, but when accessing the fragment that is supposed to display the ListView, it's blank. I believe I'm messing up in the ASyncTask and the adapter, any help would greatly be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You return `levelList` in `doInBackground`, but you never added any items to it from the retrieved JSON. All you have is an empty `ArrayList`, so the `ListView` is empty.

Comment: @Rob at this point you're asking basic questions about programming and Java. The short answer is no. Your ArrayList is of type HashMap<String, String> and since the json is a JSONObject, it cannot be added to your ArrayList. Seems like you're rubbing up against your own limitations in trying to follow the tutorial. My advice is to spend some time learning about Collections and programming in general and then try the tutorial again.